# Эмулирование нажатия enter

Tags: javascript

Можно ли эмулировать нажатие enter через консоль ?
Допустим есть чат, где отправлять сообщение можно только когда поле input в фокусе по нажатию enter. Можно ли эмулировать это самое нажатие enter через консоль разработчика?

Comment: Ответ будет зависеть от того, какие библиотеки\фреймворки используются на клиентской стороне. Добавьте больше информации об этом.

Comment: Если хорошо гуглить, можно найти вот такую [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722096/simulating-a-keypress-event-from-javascript-console).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');
const myEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {key: 'Enter'});

app.addEventListener('keypress', handlerKeypress);
function handlerKeypress(event) {
  console.log(`event.key = ${event.key}`)
}
setTimeout(function(){
  app.dispatchEvent(myEvent)
},1000)
```

```html
<input id="app">
```

Comment: Например, в реакте или ангуляре такой код не даст желаемого результата.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, почему?

Comment: http://builtwithangular.net/project/angular-chartjs/ - сайт на Ангуляре? Скопируйте мой код в консоль, только вместо `document.getElementById('app')` напишите `document.getElementById('comment')`. Это поле `textarea` на этом сайте

Comment: Вы в примере делаете сабмит формы. Это не то же самое, что эмулировать событие нажатия на `Enter`. Надеюсь, вы это понимаете. Кстати, насколько я вижу, сайт не на ангуляре. Как минимум форма для обратной связи не на ангуляре.